# VBA Count how many times a text appears

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use the formula to count how many times "s" appears from D1 to Dj, but I keep getting error on

```
nS = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(i).Range(Cells(1, 4)
```

the subject is like

```
 Public Sub check()
                Dim nS As Integer
                Dim j As Integer
                Dim Row_Count As Integer
                Dim i As Integer
                j = Row_Count + 53
                nS = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(i).Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(j, 4)), "s")
                MsgBox "nS=" & nS
                MsgBox "D" & j
End Sub
```

And the first MsgBox keeps showing nS=0

Comment: remove `Worksheets(i).` or add `i = 1`

Answer (score 0):

the `Worksheets` collection starts from 1, but in your case `i` is 0